# How do I see the no. of lines added, modified and deleted between two sprints in VSTS?

Tags: git, azure-devops, project-management

I want to see the code changes between two sprints. Or the no. of lines added, modified or deleted in a sprint .searched a lot in VSTS but could not find this feature. So is there any workaround for this? My VSTS is integrated with GIT.

For now, I have tried the below command, but it requires two commit ids and I want to give sprint or time as input. And it should ignore the autogenerated files like dll, exe. And this feature can be used from any machine.

```
git diff <StartCommit> <EndCommit> --shortstat
```

It gives the below output

> 37 files changed, 79 insertions(+), 5739 deletions(-)

I  am thinking to make a windows form kind of application which takes user's credential, startdate and enddate or sprint as input and gives the added, modified and deleted files in the result.

Update:

On running the above mentioned I'm getting the error, please refer the below screenshot.
[image: Error]

Error on Bash:

[image]

Screenshot of GitK

[image]

Comment: Could you try and compare branches? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/history?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio#compare-branches

Comment: @VonC I’m in the same branch only.

Comment: Yes, bout could you use tags instead when selecting "branches"? (I don't have a Visual Studio available right now)

Comment: There’s no tag and it’s old project

Comment: OK. Then I don't know about a VSTS extension which would be able to show such a diff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the diff between two sprints, you can use below steps:

#### 1.   Check if there has commits during the specified date

First, you need to check if there has commits during the specified date:

- If there has no output for the command `git rev-list --since="startdate-1" master`, that means no commits were committed after startdate;
- If there has no output for the command `git rev-list --since="enddate-1" master`, that means no commits were committed since enddate.

Note: `startdate-1` means the day before startdate; `enddate-1` means the day before enddate.

The logic in code should be:

```
if (no output from git rev-list --since="startdata-1" master)
{
  return;
  #skip to execute following git command
}
else
{
  if (no output from git rev-list --since="enddata-1" master)
  {
    return;
    #skip to execute following git commad
  }
}
execute git diff commit commit --shortstat
```

#### 2.   Convert dates to commits

- To get the commit for the startdate:

  ```
  $(git rev-list --since="startdate-1" master --reverse | head -1)
  ```
- To get the commit for the enddate:

  ```
  $(git rev-list --since="enddate-1" master --reverse | head -1)
  ```

#### 3.   Compare with the two converted commits

Then compare the difference by the command:

```
git diff $(git rev-list --since="startdate-1" master --reverse | head -1) $(git rev-list --since="enddate-1" master --reverse | head -1) --shortstat
```

Comment: I don’t want to be dependent on git, is there any way that I can get the required result without git? For example I should be able to get the result on a machine which doesn’t have git.

Comment: If so, there is no way to achieve it. Since the checksum for each commit's changes are record inside the git repo (of the .git folder), no matter for other tools or GUIs, to check the difference between two commits must rely on GIT.

Comment: I don't want to install the GIT on the system.  I just want to use the git credentials. Can it be done?

Comment: Don't want to install git command line only or other git GUI tools (such as sourcetree, tortoiseGit etc) neither?

Comment: Just suppose I will make a windows application which takes input as startdate and enddate, It uses the above command and gives the output. I can give this windows application to my manager or some other users. They can run this application and get the result. But they dont have git on their machine

Comment: What if you add Git-Windows-Minimal nuget package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Git-Windows-Minimal/2.17.1.2) in your project so that users won't need to install git by themselves manually?

Comment: I am getting **warning: Log for 'master' only goes back to Fri, 18 May 2018 15:00:16 +0530** on running `git diff @{2018-03-05} @{2018-04-30} --shortstat`

Comment: You can filter thw warning from output since except the waring, the response show the difference correctly.

Comment: It's not showing any result, it's showing only the warning.

Comment: @viveknuna considering there may not take actions in the git repo (no reflog), I updated the way to get the commits for startdate and enddate. You can have a try.

Comment: I am getting **'head' is not recognized as an internal or external command** on running the above command

Comment: Can you show the screen shot of the command you used and it's reponse?

Comment: I have added screenshot in your answer, I will remove it once it gets resolved

Comment: You added `^` before `HEAD`. Please remove `^`.

Comment: On bash also, I'm getting error. I have updated your question

Comment: Can you also show the commit history by execute the command `gitk`?

Comment: The reason is caused **there has no commits after the enddate you specified (2018-05-28)**. So the command `$(git rev-list --since="2018-05-28" master --reverse | head -1)~ -1` failed. And in your own code, you can check the output of the command `git rev-list --since="start/end date" master`, if there has no output, then skip to execute `git diff` command.

Comment: but it should not matter on the commits after the given enddate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172874/discussion-between-marina-liu-msft-and-vivek-nuna).

Comment: @viveknuna I updated my answer. And if you do not want to add if condition in your code, then you can execute `git diff` directly (shows in step3). And there won't show error messages even there has no commits during the specified date.

Comment: @viveknuna Does the answer helps you solve the problem?